# Динамическая загрузка js скрипта и всплывающее окно

Tags: javascript, браузер, popup

Загружаю динамически js скрипт, который представляет из себя фреймворк с графической частью.

При загрузке страницы  происходит странный эффект - открывается новое окно браузера с несуществующей страницей - точнее к url странице  добавляется дополнительный элемент (было /test/- стало /test/chat - такой страницы не существует).
В фреймворке никаких редиректов нет.

Comment: Так может скрипт и создает это окно для своих целей, например так `window.open(document.URL + '/chat', ...)`

Comment: Вот именно что в скрипте нет манипуляций типа  window.open и window.location и так далее , скрипт большой . Есть манипуляции с Cookie и websocket

Comment: Вот и хочу узнать какие команды могут привести к такому странному поведению

Comment: А где его посмотреть, этот фреймворк?

Comment: Это мой фреймворк. Очень длинный . Просто хотел узнать какие команды могут прямо или косвенно привести к такому поведению. Там манипуляции с DOM. WS и Cookie

Comment: Проблема точно в фреймворке. До его инициализации такой проблемы нет

Comment: Вот и надо было ссылку на него указать

Comment: Возможно ли такое поведение быть вызвано использование метода open в классах/объектах - может это зарезервированное слово?

Comment: С чего бы это ему быть зарезервированным!?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена : удаление из классов методов open (зарезервированные слова) решило проблему.
https://html5css.ru/js/js_reserved.php